# How to filter results in Visual Studio Error List by project or file name/path name

Tags: visual-studio-2017

In my project, I've copied a javascript library. The library works fine, although the code is clearly not "perfect" due to the number of errors I get shown in the Error List in Visual Studio

However, I'm not going to fix these as the code works fine, and as such, I don't want to see them. There are over 400 of these errors and I'm more interested in the .CS (C#) files.

How can I put up rules/filters in the error list to ignore files by path/name?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it in the Error Window (AFAIK).

You can filter by Build \ IntelliSense, by Errors \ Warnings, by Solution \ Current Project \ Open Documents \ Current Document.
[image]

You also can configure warnings level and treat warnings as errors in the project properties.
[image]

But in general, I recommend using the Output Window instead of the Error Window. I can't remember the last time I actually use the Error Window...
If you use Output Window, you can use also an extension that colorizes rows based on config, which is can be helpful.

Comment: The error window is great for silly syntax errors though :) Which I make a lot of!

Comment: Yes, you right, I also make them :) But it very weak and not consist. Try to use the output window including some advance techniques (in design mode and runtime) and you will never go back to the error window ;)